# get irrelative dates in excel file using pandas python and create header and put a comment like 'date is irrelative'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

Using excel file in pandas, I want to get non relative dates and create header in excel file and put comment like 'date is irrelative'

here is my code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

source_file = 'S://users/desktop/excel_file.xlsx'

read_file = pd.read_file(source_file)
read_file.loc[(read_file['name'] =='jones'),'comment']='jones has a dog'
read_file.loc[(read_file['Dates'] == '20-10-0019'),'comment']='date is irrelative'
```

as a example i have taken only 1 dates like '20-10-0019'. But in my case  months and dates changed. But year is constant like "0019". I need a regex using pandas in above scenerio and get irrelative and put comment like 'date is irrelative' in comment header.

Example input:

```
 names            dates    
 jones         01-01-2019
 politician    01-01-0019
 piter           nan           
 mike          06-10-2017
 william       04-04-2018
 david         19-07-0019

output be like :

 nemes                dates              comment
 jones               01-01-2019       jones has a dog
 politician          01-01-0019       date is irrelative
 piter                 nan
 mike                06-10-2017
 william             04-04-2018
 david               19-07-0019       date is irrelative
```

remaining will be blank.

Comment: if all your 'irrelative dates' (the word doesn't exist and it's not entirely clear what you mean by that, as for me, 01-01-0019 would be 'relative', since I'm pretty sure that it does not mean the year 19 AD) end with 0019 (You said this is 'constant') why don't you simply do string comparison? 
I don't know how to do this in python, I'm a C# programmer, so I didn't put this in an answer, but I'd simply convert the excel file to csv, split by the separator into an array, and then do List<string> irrelatDates = splitStringArray.Where(x => x.EndsWith("0019").ToList() and be mostly done with it.